# Question regarding dielectric breakdown (especially for stun guns)

Tags: high-voltage, practical, dielectric-breakdown

This question occurred to me after looking at some models of stun guns.  What I noticed was that some of them like one I bought had metal extensions sort of like prongs, or like tiny metal cones.  I think the idea of them is to hurt an attacker in an additional way and to press the electrodes into their clothing.  What I thought of was if the extensions/prongs were not surrounded by clothing and there was a little air around them, would it not shock someone with clothing that has a higher breakdown voltage than the air gap between the electrodes?  In other words, for a million volt stun gun, would there need to be about 30 cm of distance between the electrodes, or they would need to be pressed with sufficient pressure so as to not leave any parts of the metal exposed?  In relation to that, does having pointed electrodes make the current flow out of the points and through clothing rather than around because the electric field strength is stronger near edges/corners of conductors?

Comment: I have not heard of a 'legal' stun gun with more than 50,000 volts output. There is talk of using gas discharge tubes in the gun so the initial spark is more intense, but for a shorter duration. 30 cm is not a typical stun gun, which has about a 1 cm gap.

Comment: yeah, a million volt stun gunt has 950,000 volts of "hype".

Comment: Marketing volts are significantly smaller than the kind you measure with a voltmeter.

Comment: 50,000,0000 mV Perhaps?